# Ui autocomplete show URL even with no results

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I want to display an URL inside the suggestion list even if there is no results.

For now, I have this code: URL is display only with results in the `open()` function.

Is it possible to add a custom URL, after the first letter, even if I have no results?

```
$(function(){
  $( "#search" ).autocomplete({
    minLength: 1,
    source:'source',
    html: true, 
    open: function(event, ui){
      var term = $('#search').val(); 
      $("<br /><li><a href='/search-"+term+"'>Recherche complète pour "+term+"</a></li>").appendTo('ul.ui-autocomplete');
    }
  })
  .autocomplete( "instance" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
    return $( "<li><div><img src='"+item.avatar+"'>&nbsp;<a href='"+item.value+"'>"+item.value+"</a><span class=\"alias_tweet_search\">@"+item.value+"</span></div></li>" ).appendTo( ul );
  };
});
```

Comment: Can you format your code before posting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved , here is the code

```
  $(function(){
    $( "#search" ).autocomplete({
      minLength: 1,
      source:'source',
      open: function(event, ui){
        var term = $('#search').val(); 
        var addnew = "<br /><li>&nbsp;<a href='/search-"+term+"'>Search for   "+term"</a></li>";
       $(".ui-autocomplete").append(addnew);
    },
     response: function(event, ui) {
       if (!ui.content.length) {
            var noResult = { value:"",label:"No results found" };                   
               ui.content.push(noResult);}                 
    },
  })
    .autocomplete( "instance" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
      if(item.value == '')
      {
        return $ ( "<li>&nbsp;Aucune suggestion trouvée</li>" ).appendTo( ul );
      }
      else
      {
    return $( "<li><div class=\"test\"><img src='"+item.avatar+"'>&nbsp;<a href='/"+item.value+"'>"+item.value+"</a><span class=\"alias_tweet_search\">@"+item.value+"</span></div></li>" ).appendTo( ul );
      }
  };
});
```